# How to install webpack-dev-server? Getting unmet dependencies

Tags: npm, webpack

I used:

```
npm install -g webpack
npm install -g webpack-dev-server
```

I keep getting:

```
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@>=1.3.0 <3
└─┬ webpack-dev-server@1.16.2 
  └── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@1 || ^2.1.0-beta
```

I then tried:

```
npm install webpack@2.1.0-beta.25 -g
```

Trying npm install webpack-dev-server still yields the same error. What gives?

Comment: I tried on my own machine without any issues of peer deps. My guess is youre doing something wrong using globals, and whats in your project

Comment: Im using latest version and not the stable. Is there a way to check/resolve global issues? I am still getting the same error. Using OSX.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
npm install --save-dev webpack
npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-server
```

Try these commands... it worked for me...

Comment: So you shouldnt be installing webpack in global scope? The documentation for webpack shows that they install it into global scope, not sure why dev server needs local..

Answer (score 0):

This article may also help:

http://ia.njamieson.co.uk/2017/01/21/a-very-simple-guide-setting-up-webpack-dev-server-on-a-mac-using-terminal/

```
npm install --save-dev webpack webpack-dev-server
```

Run your webpack-dev-server assuming your files are in a src folder:

```
webpack-dev-server --content-base=src
```